# How to connect an ASP.NET web application to the phone attached to the COM Port?

Tags: asp.net, sms, serial-port

I am developing a application which can receive SMS messages and after reading it to send replies as SMS.
For this, I am attaching a nokia 7210 Supernova via USB to act as the GSM  modem for showing demo.
This is what in my mind. But I don't know how to proceed with this. Can anyone give me good guidance??
I found a way using AT commands.
I just tested using this code snippet:
I tried to dial a number. But nothing happened in the phone.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String mobileNumber = "121312";
            SerialPort sp1 = new SerialPort("COM10", 9600);
            sp1.Open();
            sp1.WriteLine("ATD" + mobileNumber + ";");
            sp1.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think this is a good idea. there are tons of webservices which are cheaper and faster. 
the other option if you want 100% control is to connect to a sms gateway of a provider via modem / isdn.

Comment: Iam looking to control the phone using AT commands. It will be no-cost solution, right?

Comment: this way is free, but in the end more expensive than using a webservice. atleast in germany you pay this way 10 cent for each sms.

Comment: not to mention you need something like a message queue if you have concurreent senders.

Comment: @Snoopy : I tried the link you gave. But when I ran the code with my nokia 7210 connected to COM12 port, it returned me an error as "No phone connected". i tried debugging the code, but with no success.